# AngularJS ngRepeat: how to differentiate even/odd elements?

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angular and trying to do the following:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="element in awesomeThings">
<div ng-if="$index %2 == 0">
    <td class="even">
        <a href="#">
            {{element}}
        </a>
    </td>
</div>
<div ng-if="$index %2 != 0">
    <td class="odd">
        <a href="#">
            {{element}}
        </a>
    </td>
</div>
</tr>
```

for the above code, both `ng-if` is passing. Where I'm making mistake?

Comment: index is $index with angular

Comment: no luck. Its the same result

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClassOdd

Comment: @JBNizet: Only your solution worked!

Comment: @batman what is `awesomeThings`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try `$even` and `$odd` properties. Refer the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

Like :

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="element in awesomeThings">
<div ng-if="$even">
    <td class="even">
        <a href="#">
            {{element}}
        </a>
    </td>
</div>
<div ng-if="$odd">
    <td class="odd">
        <a href="#">
            {{element}}
        </a>
    </td>
</div>
</tr>
```

Comment: Make sure you're using Angular.js 1.2.0 or newer.

Answer (score 12):

You don't need to use ng-if to check whether it's an even or odd element, that functionality is built-in already:

```
    <tr ng-repeat="element in awesomeThings">
        <span ng-class="$even ? 'odd' : 'even'">{{element}}</span>
   </tr>
```

Another built-in feature is `ng-class` which gives you several options to conditionally set a css class, here I'm using the ternary version but there are other ways to use it also.

Here is a [**working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/e7wu4fbw/8/)

Also, here is a [good article](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass) explaining more about `ng-class`

Comment: Works for me, but I don't really get the statement. I'm assuming the "$even" is the statement, but why does the first row get triggered as 'odd', while the statement is '$even'? (Finding it hard to explain this question)

Comment: @JorisDecraecker Because the statement should be: "$even ? 'even' : 'odd'" (meaning if even, put class even otherwise put odd). Of course you can use the even class when odd but I agree in the fact that the answer could be a bit confusing.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use **ng-class-even** and **ng-class-odd**.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClassEven
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClassOdd

Comment: This is a more elegant use than the selected answer and should be up :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this in css:

```
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #CCC
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #FFF
}
```

You could define style for the first item:

```
tr:first-child {
    background: #84ace6
}
```