# Angularjs conditional display in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

This can be a dumb question. But I hope you can help me with this. I'm doing something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list" class="display-item">
   <ng-include src="mytemplate.html"></ng-include>

   <div ng-if="($index%2) == 0">
      <p>An inserted content when index is an even number.</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Now this is working. The problem starts when I'm making the page responsive in all devices, cause you see when I inserted the `p` tag, it was created inside the parent `div` tag with the class `display-item`. What I want to do is put it outside the div tag so when the screen is smaller the `p` tag will not be affected by the parent tag and vise versa. So something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list" class="display-item">
   <ng-include src="mytemplate.html"></ng-include>
</div>
<div ng-if="($index%2) == 0">
   <p>An inserted content when index is an even number.</p>
</div>
```

Now the problem with the code above is `$index` is undefined on that part of the code and I know `ng-repeat` will finish iterating first before going to the second div.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Move the `ng-repeat` to a mutual parent element

Comment: You could try using $odd or $even. See this question and answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26271591/angularjs-ngrepeat-how-to-differentiate-even-odd-elements).

Comment: @Phil I think it would still be the same since ng-repeat includes the parent element in repeating.

Comment: @Nathan Thanks but I think getting the odd or even is not the problem.

Comment: @Jed yes, but it wouldn't have the `display-item` class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be easily done by using `ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end`

Try like this:

```
<div ng-repeat-start="item in list" class="display-item">
   <ng-include src="mytemplate.html"></ng-include>
</div>
<div ng-repeat-end ng-if="($index%2) == 0">
   <p>An inserted content when index is an even number.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Although it doesn't really solved my problem but it answers my question above. I totally forgot about the ng-repeat-start and end.

Answer (score 0):

@Jed, could you put a class tag on the ng-if div for an outer div? Say

```
<div ng-if="($index%2)" class="outer-div-you-want">
```

Just a thought to try.